# Sharepoint Master Page

Tags: html, asp.net, sharepoint-2013, master-pages, sharepoint-designer

I trying to move new Sharepoint Master Page put I only have a Master.file and not HTML file so when trying to upload that I'm getting an error.. Can an AP.NET even be a Master page or do I even need a HTML .file ? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLKHm.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use design manager feature, make sure you enabled publishing feature so you could convert a html file to a master page and then you could edit the master page by SharePoint designer.

[image]

[image]